# Why New I/O workers are all and always RUNNABLE?

Tags: java, multithreading, nio

I've just figured out that my Karaf OSGi container have many 'New I/O  worker' threads and all of them are always in RUNNING state.
It looks reasonable for me to see 'Server soket acceptor' threads always RUNNING as there in no use for them  'to sleep' as they are 'listening for incomming connections' all the time. Any other threads are usually in WAITING state (using different java mechanizms) 'for some work to appear to get themselves busy'.

So what are New I/O workers actually do?

```
    "New I/O  worker #31" - Thread t@772
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
        - locked <37500e09> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <857d58a> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <63863c4b> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:64)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:244)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

JVisualVM show 100% 'Running' time and 0% 'Wait' time.
Why are they not 'sleep' a while after each 'resourse availability check'? As any other threads are reasonably designed?

Comment: JavaDoc on RUNNABLE (not RUNNING): "Thread state for a runnable thread.  A thread in the runnable state is executing in the Java virtual machine but it may be waiting for other resources from the operating system such as processor."

Comment: The JVM only changes to WAITING or BLOCKED under certain conditions.  You can call a JNI method which is blocking, though the thread says it is RUNNABLE. i.e. the JVM doesn't do the scheduling it only infers what state it thinks the thread is in.

Comment: Why do you think JVM doesn't do the scheduling? If thread is blocked by some operation or resource aqusition, JVM would need to give CPU to the thread as  soon as resource is available, thus it needs to 'switch context and check' resourse availability. Doesn't it?

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych The JVM doesn't do the scheduling because the operating system does it.